# What the most efficient way of xml filtering

Tags: xml

I have Xml that looks something like this:
How can i filtering this xml for cb="1" ?
I know only xpath & DataSet are ways for filtering this xml:

```
<root>
  <node id="1">
       <node cb="0"></node>
       <node cb="0"></node>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
       <node id="21" cb="0"></node>
       <node id="22" cb="1"></node>
  </node>
</root>
```

What is the most efficient way to make it like (filter by cb=1):

```
<root>
   <node id="2">
        <node id="22" cb="1"></node>
   </node>
 </root>
```

With regards,
Evgeniy Vinnikov

Comment: What have you tried? What is your platform? How do you define "efficiency"?

Comment: Hi Bob , i try convert one Xml to another , filtered Xml in Dot.net environment in C#

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged a language, so I'll offer perl as a solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub process_node {
    my ( $twig, $node ) = @_;
    if ( $node->has_children ) {
        my $match = $node->get_xpath( './node[@cb="1"]', 0 );
        if ( not defined $match ) {
            $node->delete;
        }
    }
    else {

        if (   not defined $node->att('cb')
            or not $node->att('cb') eq "1" )
        {
            $node->delete;
        }
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 'node' => \&process_node, },
)->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
  <node id="1">
       <node cb="0"></node>
       <node cb="0"></node>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
       <node id="21" cb="0"></node>
       <node id="22" cb="1"></node>
  </node>
</root>
```

This will produce:

```
<root>
  <node id="2">
    <node cb="1" id="22"></node>
  </node>
</root>
```